# How to auto deploy latest image for a certain version

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have a request to make OCP monitoring images changes in OSR for a certain version, for example: monitoring version 1, if image 1.1 is published to OSR, pod will be update to use that version automatically, if 1.2 is published later, pod will automatically use v1.2.

Is this possible with OCP and OSR?

Best regards

Lan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [an image stream](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#image-streams) which references a docker registry and an [image change trigger](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/deployments.html#image-change-trigger) when the image is changed the trigger will update the deployment.

Comment: While this method only make OCP monitoring the changes for identified version, for example: 1.1. what I want to implement is to make OCP monitoring version 1.x, when 1.2 comes in, OCP will auto redeploy the pod.

Comment: When using latest as version in IS trigger, seems OCP only monitoring version "latest", if I don't define "latest" version in IS, trigger doesn't work.